# Rounding Corners: How to calculate Fillet radius?

Tags: geometry, circles

How do I find the maximum rounding I can apply to either corner for any amount of rounding on the other corner?

The all circles are perfect circles, but I can't figure out the max size of the rounding possible, or how to calculate it's position. Here's some images that describe the problem.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Your question is difficult to read in this form, please redraw with better notation for points, lengths and angles.